# xCode 3.2.1 Alien Leak

Tags: iphone, instruments, memory-leaks

Used code in entire project:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
     UITabBarController *tb = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     [window addSubview:tb.view];
     [tb release];

     [window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
     [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

When the UITabBarController is added to the window view the following leak is detected bij Instruments:

> Leaked Object: Malloc 128 Bytes
>
> Address : 0x391ee70
>
> Size : 128 Bytes
>
> Responsible Library : CoreGraphics
>
> Responsible Frame :
>   open_handle_to_dylib_path

This same issue occurs with UINavigationController, but does not appear with UIViewController.

Specs:

> Mac OS X 10.6.2
>
> xCode 3.2.1
>
> Instruments 2.0.1
>
> Compiled for iPhone Simulator 3.1.3 | Debug

Comment: You'd better talk to the US Government about that...

Comment: Somehow I have the feeling that, that won't work.

Comment: Strangly enough, the leak does not occur when I compile it for Device 3.1.3 | Debug.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a recurring issue - the app I'm currently working on is exhibiting the identical leak (only on the Simulator - not on the device). Would like to have a leak-free product for release, but this annoyance persists. I suppose it's not worth worrying too much about.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about it. I'm sure your app will run fine with a one time 128 byte leak.

Comment: +1 Only worth worrying if it's a continuously occurring leak.

Comment: Still, I like my application to be leak free. I would like to know if the same leak appears with your xCodes.